# How to get HTML code from an url has DnP Firewall (PHP)

Tags: php, html, get, firewall

I used file_get_contents and simple html dom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) but can't get HTML of this URL:

http://forum.hui.vn/Thread-nhung-hanh-dong-ngo-ngan-cua-dan-ong-15824?action=lastpost

The HTML I was got is DnP Firewall. Please help to get HTML code from an url has DnP Firewall. Thank you!

Comment: That's the same content you get when you invoke it in the browser. What else did you expect? Otherwise contact the hoster and ask how to skip the intro page.

Answer (score 0):

You need cookies enabled in your solution.
This site is attempting to set a session id cookie, which you need to respond back with in order to not get a new session every time.

Basically you need to parse through the header of the server response you initially get, and send back that same cookie in a new response. to the location specified in the form 'action' on that page:

```
<form name=dnp_firewall method=get action=dnp_fw.php>
<input type=hidden value="/Thread-nhung-hanh-dong-ngo-ngan-cua-dan-ong-15824?action=lastpost" name="dnp_firewall_redirect">
<input type=submit value=" " alt="Click to continue to your destination" style="background-image:url(default.png); height:350px; width:575px; cursor:pointer;
```

In this case you'd form your response something like this:

```
dnp_fw.php?dnp_firewall_redirect=/Thread-nhung-hanh-dong-ngo-ngan-cua-dan-ong-15824?action=lastpost&submit=%20
```

Then you'll need to process any redirects that occur as a result of these actions..

I'd also suggest setting your UserAgent to something common like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
```

Or you could just use Curl
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php